# Get CP's current selected locale

Tags: plugin-development, localization

[image]

Is there an easier way to get the CP's currently selected locale? In my plugin I am currently using this method.

```
public function getCurrentLocale() {
    $id = is_array($this->value) ? $this->value[0] : false;
    $segments = craft()->request->segments;
    $lastSegment = end($segments);
    $locales = craft()->elements->getEnabledLocalesForElement($id);

    if (in_array($lastSegment, $locales)) {
        return $lastSegment;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: My current method doesn't work if my plugin's field type is being used in globals, because in globals the locale is located in a different segment position.

Comment: Do you mean the locale that you're currently viewing the control panel in, or if you're viewing an entry, the locale that you're viewing the entry in?

Comment: The locale I am currently viewing the entry in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is in the context of an [event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entry-api-events), in which case you've got access to the EntryModel.

If so, `$entryModel->locale` should be what you're looking for.